# OpenTracing + Jaeger: SQL traces not getting reported

Tags: jaeger, opentracing

I am following all the instructions mentioned here: https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-jdbc

I assumed that with these steps the traces related to JDBC operations will automatically start getting reported. However, in the logs, I only see this below and nothing in Jaeger UI.

```
[main] INFO io.jaegertracing.Configuration - Initialized tracer=JaegerTracer(version=Java-0.35.4, serviceName=my-svc, reporter=CompositeReporter(reporters=[RemoteReporter(sender=HttpSender(), closeEnqueueTimeout=1000), LoggingReporter(logger=org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger(io.jaegertracing.internal.reporters.LoggingReporter))]), sampler=ConstSampler(decision=true, tags={sampler.type=const, sampler.param=true}), tags={hostname=mypc.local, jaeger.version=Java-0.35.4, ip=127.0.0.1}, zipkinSharedRpcSpan=false, expandExceptionLogs=false, useTraceId128Bit=false)
```

Can someone please show an example of how to achieve this? I am using below versions:

opentracing-api-0.33.0
opentracing-jdbc-0.2.10
opentracing-util-0.33.0
jaeger-core-0.35.4

Here's the abstract that I have attempted. Is there anything else I need to do?

```
// Jaeger Tracer
private static Tracer tracer = initTracer();

…

public static Tracer initTracer() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    System.setProperty("JAEGER_ENDPOINT", "http://collector-hostt:14268/api/traces");

    TracingDriver.load();
    TracingDriver.setInterceptorMode(true);
    TracingDriver.setInterceptorProperty(true);
    TracingDriver.setTraceEnabled(true);

    SamplerConfiguration samplerConfig = SamplerConfiguration
            .fromEnv()
            .withType(ConstSampler.TYPE)
            .withParam(1);

    ReporterConfiguration reporterConfig = ReporterConfiguration
            .fromEnv()
            .withLogSpans(true);

    Configuration config = new Configuration("my-svc")
            .withSampler(samplerConfig)
            .withReporter(reporterConfig);

    tracer = config.getTracer();

    GlobalTracer.registerIfAbsent(tracer);

    return tracer;
}
```

And then this is the code around database call:

```
Span span = tracer.buildSpan("getAuthAccount").start();
span.setTag(Tags.SPAN_KIND.getKey(), Tags.SPAN_KIND_CLIENT);
this.accountDao.getAccount(username, password);
span.finish();
```

The database config is:

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/myDB"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" auth="Container"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
        username="tcuser" password="quality"
        driverClassName="io.opentracing.contrib.jdbc.TracingDriver"
        url="jdbc:tracing:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true&amp;traceWithActiveSpanOnly=true"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="60000"
        testOnBorrow="true" testOnReturn="false" testWhileIdle="true"
        validationInterval="1800000" validationQuery="SELECT 1"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? If yes, could you post the correct configuration?

Comment: can you please post correct answer.I am also getting same problem